# SpringMVC: не открывается страница

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404

В веб-разработке новичок. Делал всё по одному туториалу, но на этапе проверки работоспособности веб-сервиса столкнулся с проблемой: созданная страница не открывается.

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта:]

Содержимое файла `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.3.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.3.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.3.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5
    implementation group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring5', version: '3.0.12.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
}
```

Содержимое файла `HelloController.java`:

```
package mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering/>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Содержимое файла `applicationContextMVC.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mvc"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Ну и содержимое файла `hello_world.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

В итоге, если перейти по адресу `http://localhost:8080/hello-world`, появляется вот такой результат:

[image: Нерабочая страница локалхост]

Самое интересное, что стартовая страница `index.jsp` открывается нормально.

Прошу помочь, перекопал интернет, но нигде не нашёл в чём может быть проблема (а ведь пример достаточно простой).

Comment: Пересобрал всё на сборщике maven и всё заработало. В чём было дело так и не понял.

Comment: Где файл `pom.xml`?

Comment: @RomanC, сборщик gradle не включает в себя файл `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было в версии Tomcat. 8 и 10 не работает, а вот на 9 всё запустилось без проблем.